# Мэтт Зандстра "PHP. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования. 3-е издание"

Tags: php, книги

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, отыскать эту книгу в электронном формате. Именно **3 издание**.

Comment: У меня есть 3-е издание в бумаге. Могу отдать в Питере за ненадобностью (приобрел новое издание).

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это не сайт для поиска ссылок на книги.

Answer (score 1):

[PHP. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5648968/). (3-е издание).